# swift generic constraint type is also a return type

Tags: swift, generics, generic-associated-types

```
protocol Builder {
    associatedtype Output where Output: MyProtocol
    func build() -> Output?
}

// concrete type
struct ABuilder: Builder {
       func builder() -> MyProtocol {
           if someCondition {
               return aSubClassOfMyProtocol
           } else {
               return anotherSubClassOfMyProtocol
           }
       }
}
```

`MyProtocol` is a protocol type. It is also the `Output` constraint. Because the concrete Builder `ABuilder` is going to return two different sub class types that conform `MyProtocol`. How can I make the generic constraint work?

I am trying to make the generic constraint be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `build()` function generic or use typecasting. Anyway this two ways determine concrete type outside of method not inside.
So first of all you need to remove `associatedtype`. If you specify associated type `Output` it means that the implementation of your `Builder` protocol should return some concrete type which conforms to `MyProtocol`. If you want your `Builder` to return any type which conforms to `MyProtocol` not the concrete one specified for this implementation of Builder then you shouldn't declare any associated types.

Let's see how type casting can work:

```
protocol Builder {
    func build() -> MyProtocol?
}

struct ABuilder: Builder {
    func build() -> MyProtocol? {
        // some code
    }
}

let builder = ABuilder()
guard let a = builder.build() as? SomeClass else { return }
```

Or we can use generic approach:

```
protocol Builder {
    func build<T: MyProtocol>() -> T?
}

struct ABuilder: Builder {
    func build<T: MyProtocol>() -> T? {
        // some code
    }
}

let builder = ABuilder()
let a: SomeClass = builder.build()
```

You can read more about that [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html), [here](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/associated-types-protocols/) and [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html). Moreover I strongly recommend watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_m6DxTEisR8&t=862s) which describes all the limitations of generics in swift.

Comment: I need the ABuilder to return the concrete types. But the only limitation is that if it returns some different types, that the return type of the `build()` can not be specified as a concrete type. If I use `MyProtocol` then it will conflict to the generic constraint.

Comment: I think I understood you so I updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

I think you are correct that having the typecasting outside the `Builder` is a better way. I also found another possibility. The difference is that we have the concrete class types from the `build` function.

```
    protocol MyProtocol { }

    protocol Builder {
        associatedtype Output
        func build() -> Output?
    }

    struct ASubClassOfMyProtocol: MyProtocol {}

    struct AnotherSubClassOfMyProtocol: MyProtocol {}

    struct ABuilder: Builder {
        func build() -> (any MyProtocol)? {
            if Int.random(in: 0...10) < 5 {
                return ASubClassOfMyProtocol()
            } else {
                return AnotherSubClassOfMyProtocol()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need any in implementation or associatedtype in protocol. Declaring associated in Builder protocol will put excessive constraints on your code. You will need to use Builder for generic constraints. On the contrary it seems that you don't need that kind of limitation here. So I don't recommend writing your code like that until you fully understand why you are doing it.

Comment: I use associated type is to get the concrete class type of objects from `build` function.  The issue is that the `build` function is going to return multiple types of concrete object. So I think `func build() -> (any MyProtocol)?` would work in my case.

Comment: It's just excessive